# php и cron не выполняется скрипт

Tags: php, cron

```
* * * * * d:/test/test.php
```

в crontab записал такую команду, вместо исполнения этого скрипта он просто открывает файл, подскажите пожалуйста как запустить этот скрипт

Comment: `php "d:\test\test.php"` ? у вас файл не сам же выполняется, его интерпретатор должен обработать

Comment: @teran, не подскажете как можно его запускать

Comment: я разве строку для запуска исправленную в комменте выше не написал? или это не работает? Если не работает, то внесите путь к `php.exe` в переменную окружения `PATH`. То есть запустить вы должны интерпретатор пхп, и указать ему на вход имя вашего скрипта.

Comment: @teran, спасибо, всё сработало

Comment: оформил ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически `cron` для вас делает то, что вы ему указали - выполняет указанный файл. Действием по умолчанию для `php` файлов в винде у вас является его открытие в редакторе, что и происходит.
Вам же  надо выполнить файл с помощью интерпретатора пхп. Для  этого в кроне надо запустить `php.exe` и указать ему путь к обрабатываемому файлу. В результате ваша команда на запуск должна иметь следующий вид:

```
* * * * * php "d:\test\test.php"
```

Данная команда будет работать, если путь к директории, где расположен, `php.exe` прописан в переменной окружения `PATH`. В противном случае, вам понадобится либо добавить эту директорию в `PATH`, либо указать полный путь до файла `php.exe`.

*Формально, если вернуться к исходной команде, то она тоже может работать. Однако, для этого вам понадобится настроить действие по умолчанию для php-файлов и выбрать в качестве программы по умолчанию сам интерпретатор php.exe, а  не текстовый редактор.